# Limit String Twig

Tags: templates, symfony, twig

How can I limit a string length? I'm getting a description value from my database, but I want to **only** display a number of specific characters.

- How can I do this in my twig template?
- Is it better to do it within my controller?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try with **Truncate** function:

First, you need to activated **Text extension**:

```
# app/config/config.yml
  services:
    twig.extension.text:
        class: Twig_Extensions_Extension_Text
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

Then, you can call `truncate()` helper within your Twig template as follow:

```
{{ variable.description | truncate(100, true) }}
```

Comment: There should not be a space between the pipe and the filter name: `|truncate`, otherwise twig looks for a filter called ` truncate` (with preceeding space).

Comment: First of all, we must install the twig extensions library. It's [here](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig-extensions).

Answer (score 26):

Try this :

```twig
{{ entity.description|striptags|slice(0, 40) }}
```

1. the [`striptags` filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/striptags.html) will remove the HTML tags, this will avoid to cut a tag in 2, example of this base case: `Text ... <img src="http://examp`
2. the [`slice` filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/slice.html) will cut the text, keeping only the 40 first characters

Comment: I can verify this works. I was creating a content type called excerpt and I needed to have a small description with a max of 100 characters.

Answer (score 14):

I used this to truncate blog posts and show an ellipsis..

```
{{ post.excerpt|striptags|length > 100 ? post.excerpt|striptags|slice(0, 100) ~ '...' : post.excerpt|striptags }}
```

If the post excerpt length is greater than 100 characters then `slice` it at the 100s character starting from the first one and append an '...'
Otherwise show full text..

Comment: `striptags` is used to calculate the length of the string but not to truncate the string. What happen if the string starts with a tag?

Comment: What do you suggest ?

Comment: Apply `striptags` before the second `slice`.

Comment: @A.L Sorry missed that

Answer (score 1):

So there's a couple of options listed above that aren't given any detail, so here's a bit more info:

```
{{ variable.description|truncate(100) }}
```

This will cut your text off at 100 characters exactly. The problem here is that if the 100th character is in the middle of a word, that word will be cut in half.

So to work around this, we can add 'true' into the truncate call:

```
{{ variable.description|truncate(100, true) }}
```

When we do this, truncate will check to see if we are in the middle of a word at the cut-off point and if we are, it will cut the string at the end of that word.

If we're also looking to truncate a string that may contain some HTML, we need to strip those tags away first:

```
{{ (variable.description|striptags)|truncate(100) }}
```

The only slight disadvantage to this is that we will lose any newline characters (such as those built into paragraph tags). If you are truncating a relatively short string though, this will possibly not be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not an answer to your specific question since you want to truncate to a certain number of characters, but something similar can also be achieved using CSS. That is unless you are still supporting IE8 and IE9 then there are some caveats.

With text-overflow this can be done using the ellipses value. Here is a sample from CSS-TRICKS:

```
.truncate {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

This will allow you to truncate the text to the containers width, HOWEVER, for specific character counts the accepted TWIG resolution with the **TRUNCATE** function works perfectly.

**REFERENCE:** https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/

Answer (score 0):

You could use this Twig extension:

Usage

```
{{ text|ellipsis(20) }}
{{ text|ellipsis(20, '///') }}
```

---

```
namespace AppBundle\Twig;

//src/AppBundle/Twig/TwigTextExtension.php
class TwigTextExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('ellipsis', array($this, 'ellipsisFilter')),
        );
    }

    public function ellipsisFilter($text, $maxLen = 50, $ellipsis = '...')
    {
        if ( strlen($text) <= $maxLen)
            return $text;
        return substr($text, 0, $maxLen-3).$ellipsis;

    }
}
```

Register it as a service in services.yml

```
services:
    twig.extension.twigtext:
        class: AppBundle\Twig\TwigTextExtension
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```