# Only display certain number of characters in textarea

Tags: php, symfony

I am making an app with symfony that displays text that was entered into a text area (and saved to a database). The only problem is that if the user enters a lot of text (which is expected) the table shows it all and it doesn't look good. Is there a way to only show a certain number of characters from what was entered and just have a "..." after the desired number of characters is displayed? I am thinking I will need to use php but searched for a while and could not find anything on how to do so.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limit String Twig](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491989/limit-string-twig)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work by using `slice` in Twig.

`<td>{{ entity.notes|length > 45 ? entity.notes|slice(0, 45) ~ '...' : entity.notes }}</td>`