# How to truncate a twig array [row] in a controller?

Tags: twig, truncate

I have some twig arrays to display on a datatable.

```
              `  $values = array(
                $row['member'] . '-' . $row['email'],
                $row['transactionDate'],
                $row['currency'],
                $row['amount'],
                empty($row['amountReceived']) ? '0.00' : $row['amountReceived'],
                $row['status'],
                $row['status'] == 'Pending' ? $action : ''
            );`
```

That is on a controller, and it shows and works, but i want to truncate the member & email array result.

I have tried |`truncate(5)`, but this does not work within the row variable.

Any ideas?

I have tried `[email|truncate(5)],` but this does not work within the row variable.

Comment: your `$values` array doesn't contain any keys, how are you able in twig to use the `email` variable?  Can you share more of the controller code and twig code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit String Twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491989/limit-string-twig)

Answer (score 0):

You need the Symfony String Component. This will install the `u` filter. Then you can use it to truncate your strings.

```
{{ row.email|u.truncate(8) }}
```

as @Leroy mentioned in his comment, you probably should use keys (like I have in the example above).

[Docs ref](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/u.html)

Comment: Why not just use the vanilla [slice](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/slice.html)?